# Case of poor Python 're' performance

Tags: python, regex

A Sublime package I'm using for [autocompletion in lua](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LuaAutocomplete) uses Python's 're' module, but one regex is causing major slowdowns. Here's a minimal example:

```
import re
rx = re.compile(r"\bfunction(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9._]*)?\(((?:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|\.\.\.|,\s*)*)\)")
rx.match('function f(aaaaaaa, bbbbbbbb, cccccccc, ddddddd eeeeee)')  # Very slow
rx.match('function f(aaaaaaa, bbbbbbbb, cccccccc, ddddddd, eeeeee)')  # Adding a comma between the last function arguments in the string fixes it.
```

I'm out of my depth with regex debugging, but [this seems relevant](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html), though it's over my head.

Does anyone know an equivalent pattern I can use, but which has good performance?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe [submit a bug report](https://github.com/ColonelThirtyTwo/LuaAutocomplete/issues)?

Comment: Relevant article: http://davidvgalbraith.com/how-i-fixed-atom/ about the same catastrophic backtracking problem.

Comment: That's because of a [*catastrophic backtracking*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) which has happened in your regex matching. Actually your regex engine wants to tries all the possibilities until it encounter a comma.

Comment: More info about catastrophic backtracking: http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the pattern contains a `*`-quantified `*` quantifier: `(?:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|\.\.\.|,\s*)*`. These nested quantifiers must be avoided. If you cannot re-arrange the alternatives into subsequent (optional) groups, possessive quantifiers or atomic groups usually help.

Python `re` does not support possessive quantifiers, nor does it support atomic groups.

However, you can use a version with an emulated atomic group:

```
\bfunction(?:\s+[a-zA-Z0-9._]*)?\(((?:(?=([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))\2|\.\.\.|,\s*)*)\)
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` subpattern is placed into a capturing group that is enclosed with a positive lookbehind. The `(?=([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*))\2` is almost equivalent (as it matches the same stuff) to `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` but it makes the subpattern atomic (so, in other flavors it would look like `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*+` or `(?>[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*+)`). The "atomic" nature of the `\2` backreference won't let backtracking go beyond `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xV3dD4/3).

Also, perhaps, you want `re.search` since your pattern starts with `\b`. Note that `re.match` can only find a match at the beginning of the string (= it is anchored at the beginning of the string).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem comes from the nested quantifiers `(?:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|\.\.\.|,\s*)*` that may cause a catastrophic backtracking when the following subpattern fails.

You can avoid this problem if you unroll<sup>*</sup> this subpattern. I used the Verbose mode to make it more readable:

```
re.compile(r'''\bfunction\b \s*[a-zA-Z0-9._]*
\(

(
  (?:
    (?:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|\.\.\.)
    (?: ,\s* (?:[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*|\.\.\.) )*
  )?
)

\)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/fQ6aF4/1)

*<sup>(*)</sup>: basically the idea is to change `(a*|b)*` to `a*(ba*)*`*